# How to access multiple groups of nested JSON elements in C#?

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I have a JSON being received from a public API that follows the structure below.

```
   [
     {
"ID": "12345",
"company": [
  {
    "contract_ID": "abc5678",
    "company": [
      {
        "company_name": "HelloWorld",
        "company_logo": "HW",
        "invested": "2000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "contract_ID": "67891",
    "company": [
      {
        "company_name": "GoodBye",
        "company_logo": "GB",
        "invested": "500"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "contract_ID": "32658",
    "company": [
      {
        "company_name": "YesNo",
        "company_logo": "YN",
        "invested": "1500"
      }
    ]
  }
]
   }
     ]
```

I've tried several different methods of parsing, whether it be JTokens/JArrays or various classes. Something like the following allows me to access the first group of values (company_name, company_logo, invested), but I cannot iterate through to find the other two.

```
            //receiving the json data
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
            var fullJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
            Debug.Log(fullJSON);

            //trying to parse it down to just the data I need
            JToken token = JToken.Parse("{\"root\":" + responseString + "}");
            Debug.Log(token);
            JArray assets = (JArray)token.SelectToken("root[0].assets");
            Debug.Log(assets);
            JToken dig = JToken.Parse("{\"root\":" + assets + "}");
            Debug.Log(dig);
            JArray assetsNested = (JArray)dig.SelectToken("root[0].assets");
            Debug.Log(assetsNested);
```

My goal is to extract the contract_ID and then the associated company_name, company_logo, and invested items. For example, abc5678, HelloWorld, HW, and 2000 would be one of the three datasets needed.

Comment: It would definitely be easier if you just deserialized to some C# classes that match the shape of your JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to deserialize this properly and keep your code maintainable is to use concrete classes. For example:

```
public sealed class Company
{
    [JsonProperty("contract_ID")]
    public string ContractID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("company")]
    public List<CompanyDefinition> CompanyDefinitions { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CompanyDefinition
{
    [JsonProperty("company_name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("company_logo")]
    public string CompanyLogo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("invested")]
    public string Invested { get; set; }
}

public sealed class RootCompany
{
    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("company")]
    public List<Company> Company { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you simply deserialize. For example, if you are pulling from a file you could do this:

```
using(var sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\path\to\json.json"))
using(var jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    var result = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<RootCompany[]>(jtr);

    foreach(var r in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Company ID: {r.ID}");
        foreach(var c in r.Company)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ContractID: {c.ContractID}");
            foreach(var d in c.CompanyDefinitions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {d.CompanyName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Invested: {d.Invested}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Company Logo: {d.CompanyLogo}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When something changes with your models, you won't have to dig through lines upon lines of hard-to-read token selection code. You just update your models.

Comment: This was extremely helpful - I am new to net related coding and there seem to be a lot of different approaches out there. Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: As an aside for anyone else looking to get started, this helped me: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/from-zero-to-hero-in-json-with-c-shar/

Comment: In VS you can under the Edit meny go to "Paste special" and select "Paste JSON as Classes". In this way you can easily create classes for deserializing your JSON body.

Comment: @K.J.M.O. -- Whoa... I've been using 3rd party websites to do this. That's pretty sweet. Thanks for the tip!